# How to open a file with compatible app(s)

Tags: android, file

I have an android app in which the user should be able to tap a file and it should provide options/chooser which lists the possible apps that can play/view the content.

So without hardcoding it as a music/video/pdf or whatever , is there a way to dynamically let the suitable app play the file because the file extension could be anything.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supply the MIME type of the file in the `Intent` you use with `startActivity()`, and Android will supply a chooser automatically if appropriate.

It is up to you to find a suitable MIME type. The `android.webkit.MimeTypeMap` utility class can help with this, for some common MIME types. You can also save the MIME type when you downloaded the file from the Web server, if applicable.